# Is multithreading an API application a thing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, .net-core, api-design

I'm learning C#/DOTNET as one of the main reasons are incredible speeds over Node.js and OO syntax.

Now the tutorial I am following all of a sudden introduced async, and that's cool, but I could have done that with Node.js as well, so I feel a little disappointed.

My thought was maybe we could take this to the next level with Multithreading, but a lot of questions came up, with discrepancy in the database (like thread one is expecting to get data that thread two updated, but thread two was not executed before thread one retrieved, so thread one is working with an outdated data).

And searching for this seems to return very little information, mostly it's people misunderstanding multithreading and asynchronous programing.

So I'm guessing you would not want to mix API with multithreading?

Comment: That’s quite broad a question. Where would you use multi threading? What would it achieve? What would the threads do? There isn’t a single answer to this.

Comment: Personally, I will not multithread an API. I will always do a first come, first serve approach.

I also don't see any use-case for multithreading in an API. I assume this is a `Web API` you are referring to?

The only place I have used multithreading in data processing software, is in services, and nothing else. Do you have a possible use-case?

Comment: "So I'm guessing you would not want to mix API with multithreading?" - The issue here isn't anything specifically to do with an API. Multithreading can be difficult to get right for all coding. A better question is "So I'm guessing you would not want to mix coding with multithreading?". But that's obviously not the case. Multithreading is hard.

Comment: `you would not want to mix API with multithreading?` on the contrary, you're already doing it. For starters, all requests are served by a different thread. In individual actions/endpoints, you're using async/await to release the request thread while waiting for IO operations. Hosted services run in the background to process long-running jobs

Comment: `with discrepancy in the database` you get that with badly written desktop applications as well. This has nothing to do with APIs. They'd be useless if they could only process one request at a time

Comment: `I could have done that with Node.js as well` not really. It's not just that JavaScript got `async/await` from C#. Node still can't use more than one thread per request. C# can. You could start 10 concurrent HTTP calls and await all of them. If your service is meant to process lots of data, you can use Parallel LINQ to use all available cores to crunch in-memory data. Whether you should do that or not is another discussion - cores used for processing can't serve requests

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a thing, and you're already doing it with async tasks.

.NET has a Task Scheduler that assigns your tasks to available threads from the Thread Pool. Default behavior is to create a pool of threads for each available CPU.

Clarification: this doesn't mean 1 task : 1 thread. There's a large collection of work to be done by a number of workers. Scheduler hands a worker a job, worker works until it's done or an 'await' is reached.

From the perspective of a regular async method, it can be hard to see where the 'multi-threading' comes into play. There isn't an obvious difference between Get() and await GetAsync() when your code has to sit and wait either way.

But it's not always about your code. This example might make it more clear.

```
List<Task> work = new();
foreach(var uri in uriList)
{
    work.Add(http.GetAsync(uri));
}
await Task.WhenAll(work);
```

This code will execute all those GetAsyncs at the same time.

The framework making your API work is doing something similar. It would be pretty silly if the whole server was tied up because a single user requested a big file over dialup.

Comment: Required reading: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: There are certain things the framework does that I am happy to leave in the world of magic and threading is one of them. I can watch in Resource Monitor as a big list of tasks makes each CPU core warm; that's enough to known that I've achieved 'multi-threading'.

Answer (score 0):

Async await is used for multi-threading but it is not used only for multi-threading.

I have not pesronally used/seen multi-threading in API but only console jobs. Using TPL in console jobs has improved the efficiency more than 100% for me

Async/Await is powerful and should be used for asynchronic processing in API's too.

Please go through Shiv's videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMcycFie-nk